# Implementing Apple's HTTP Live Streaming - problem with mediafilesegmenter tool

Tags: macos, streaming, media

I have MAC OS 10.6 (Snow Leopard) and according to Apple's guide on HTTP Live Streaming, the mediafilesegmenter tool should be there in /usr/bin/ directory but it isnt. There is only the mediastreamsegmenter there. I need the mediafilesegmenter tool to segment MPEG2 Transport streams.

How can I get/install the mediafilesegmenter tool?

Thanks and regards,
Farish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mediastreamsegmenter tool will also segment a file - for example:

mediastreamsegmenter -b http://some_playback_host -B stream -f \ /Library/WebServer/Documents/my_stream -p < input_file.ts

(make sure you have created the output directory "my_stream" first).

The above should segment the file into the default of 10 second chunks prefixed with the name 'stream' and also create a .m3u8 file you can point clients at.

man mediastreamsegmenter for more info.

HTH.

Comment: thanks for your reply but it doesnt work. first there is no option '-B' in mediafilesegmenter and if i remove "-B stream", it gives the same error a large number of times (unknown type 2 in pid - 0).

can you please suggest something else that might work?

Comment: There's no -B option in mediaFILEsegmenter because I am talking about mediaSTREAMsegmenter. Give mediastreamsegmenter a go.. it should be on your Snow Leopard system.

Comment: Thank you so much! Apple never updated mediafilesegmenter to work with Lion and I was pulling my hair out trying to get it to work. Using mediastreamsegmenter like this is working great!

Answer (score 3):

You can Download the current version of the HTTP Live Streaming Tools from the Apple Developer website. You can access them if you are a member of either the iPhone or Mac Developer Program. One way to navigate to the tools is to log onto connect.apple.com, then click either iPhone or QuickTime under the Downloads heading.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i had created an account as a student for the iPhone and MAC Developer program but when I login and go to connect.apple.com, i dont see the HTTP Live Streaming Tools in the downloads there.

a person in his guide had given a direct link to those tools (download) and when i clicked, it said that i dont have enough rights to access this download...

Comment: I couldn't access the file, and found out two potential causes:

1. My developer access had expired – renew this and try in 24-48 hours (it takes time for the file to appear after renewal)
2. You have to accept any new license agreements – Go to your account page and accept the new agreements (again, there's a 24-48 hour delay after doing so)